# how to replace string with same string without quotes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've some JSON data:

```
data = '''
{
  "test": "{{{test}}}"
}
'''
```

Now I want to replace `"{{{test}}}"` with `{{{test}}}` (so without quotes).
Hardcoded it works:

```
new = data.replace("\"{{{test}}}\"", "{{{test}}}")
print(new)
```

output:

```
{
    "test": {{{test}}}
}
```

But I need to import the 'test' as variable in the command so I tried:

```
variable = "test"
new = data.replace("\"{{{%s}}}\"", "{{{%s}}}" % variable)
print(new)
```

But then I got the quotes again:

```
{
    "test": "{{{test}}}"
}
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I make this work?

Comment: Typo: change to `new = data.replace("\"{{{%s}}}\"" % variable, "{{{%s}}}" % variable)`

Comment: Do you perhaps just want to replace ``"{{{`` with ``{{{``, and same for the inverted? Do you ever have one without the other?

Comment: Note that in ``data.replace("\"{{{%s}}}\"", "{{{%s}}}" % variable``, you string format only the second string. The first will stay a literal ``'"{{{%s}}}"'``.

Comment: Note that what you want [will make it invalid JSON](https://jsonlint.com/?json={%22test%22:%20{{{test}}}}).

Comment: That's true @buran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
new = data.replace("\"{{{%s}}}\"", "{{{%s}}}" % variable)
```

You're only doing the string substitution on the second value.

Here's a way that might be cleaner:

```py
substitution = "{{{%s}}}" % variable
new = data.replace('"%s"' % substitution, substitution)
```

That being said if you're doing extensive string munging like this, you may want to look into a templating library like [Jinja](https://palletsprojects.com/p/jinja/) or a compile-to-JSON language like [Jsonnet](https://jsonnet.org/). I personally prefer Jsonnet, but to each their own.